# Multiple inner join on a table where rows represent data attributes

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following user table (don't ask me why :) )

```
| id | cid | attr | text |   rdate    |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |  1  | name |  joe |    NULL    |
|  2 |  1  | date | NULL | 10.05.2014 |
|  3 |  1  | stat |   2  |    NULL    |
----------------------------------------
|  4 |  2  | name |  joe |    NULL    |
|  5 |  2  | date | NULL | 05.05.2014 |
|  6 |  2  | stat |   1  |    NULL    |
----------------------------------------
|  7 |  3  | name |  joe |    NULL    |
|  8 |  3  | date | NULL | 03.05.2014 |
|  9 |  3  | stat |   2  |    NULL    |
```

As you can see every user's attribute (name, date, stat) is a row in the table. 
Attributes with the same cid belong to the same user.

I would like to delete all the entries which refer to a user whose attribute date is before 08.05.2014 AND whose attribute stat is not 2. So after running this query the table will be:

```
| id | cid | attr | text |   rdate    |
---------------------------------------
|  1 |  1  | name |  joe |    NULL    |
|  2 |  1  | date | NULL | 10.05.2014 |
|  3 |  1  | stat |   2  |    NULL    |
----------------------------------------
|  7 |  3  | name |  joe |    NULL    |
|  8 |  3  | date |  joe | 03.05.2014 |
|  9 |  3  | stat |   2  |    NULL    |
```

Is it possible? Is this a inner join on the same table?

Comment: Wow, lots of good answers! +1 to all, even if they're repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `cid` and use the `having` clause to run group functions to check out your requirements in every single group

```
delete from your_table
where cid in
(
  select * from 
  (
    select cid
    from your_table
    group by cid
    having sum(attr = 'date' and `date` < '2014-05-08') > 0
    and sum(attr = 'stat' and `text` = 2) = 0
  ) tmp_tbl
)
```

In MySQL you can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. But you can trick MySQL with another subquery like in the example above.

Comment: You've forgotten the `stat` attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, never heard of "having"! Just a question, you are using "date" and "stat" as fields, but they are just values of attr, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a fairly simple JOIN in the delete statement:-

```
DELETE a
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b
ON a.cid = b.cid
INNER JOIN some_table c
ON a.cid = c.cid
WHERE b.attr = 'date' AND b.date < '2014-05-08'
AND c.attr = 'stat' AND c.text != '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `delete`/`join`:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         (select cid
          from table t
          group by cid
          having max(case when attr = 'date' and date < '2014-05-08') > 0 and
                 max(case when attr = 'stat' and text <> '2') > 0
         ) s
         on t.cid = s.cid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join will do :

```
Delete from mytable where cid in (select cid from
    (select t1.cid FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.cid = t2.cid
         WHERE t1.attr = 'date' AND t1.rdate < '2014-05-08' 
                AND t2.attr = 'stat' AND t2.text != 2) as sq)
```